# what if register_global is enabled

Tags: php, register-globals

I've simple captcha that works perfect when register_global is disabled and this is the correct according to PHP Manual [Using Register Globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)

But sometimes i moves to many hosting and they by default enabled register global so my captcha stop working and always gives wrong captcha even if it was entered correct.

**My question**

why it does not works if register_global is enabled as well as if disabled ?

**The code**

captcha.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
$digits_num=5;
$x_pos=25;
$y_pos=6;
$font_size=5;
function random_num($n){
$start_num = "1".str_repeat("0", $n-1);;
$end_num   = str_repeat("9", $n);
return rand($start_num, $end_num);
}
$text = random_num($digits_num);
$_SESSION["captcha_num"] = md5($text);
$captcha = imagecreatefrompng("./images/captcha.png");
$font_color['black']=imagecolorallocate($captcha, 0, 0, 0);
$font_color['white']=imagecolorallocate($captcha, 80, 73, 20);
imagestring($captcha, $font_size, $x_pos, $y_pos, $text, $font_color['white']);
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($captcha);
?>
```

The form

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="add.php">
<img src="captcha.php">
<input type="text" name="captcha_num" id="captcha_num" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

add.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if(md5($_POST['captcha_num']) != $_SESSION['captcha_num']){
echo "Wrong captcha";
}else{
echo "Good Pass it";
}
?>
```

Comment: if your web host is clueless enough to enable `register_globals`, pick another web host...

Comment: You might as well post that as an answer IMHO @Alnitak :-)

Comment: You have my upvote if you do :)

Comment: "pick another web host" is a pretty poor answer (but good solution), since obviously this is a real problem, especially when *you* don't have control of where your code is deployed (other are people using it).

Comment: Out of curiousity, why do you hash the text before storing it in the session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual page you refered to:

> This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0
>   (...)
>   Perhaps the most controversial change in PHP is when the default value for the PHP directive register_globals went from ON to OFF in PHP » 4.2.0.

In other words: **Switch it off**.

### How can I switch  it off?

#### Option 1: With [`ini_set`](http://php.net/ini-set)

Place this code on top of you code (or in the bootstrap file if you have that)

```
ini_set('register_globals', 'Off')
```

#### Option 2: With htaccess

Make a `.htaccess` file in the root of your website and add this code to it:

```
php_flag register_globals Off
```

---

Don't ask yourself why the script is wrong if you use a bad technique, ask yourself how to switch off/avoid using the bad technique.